# Struggling to add this example/sample class

Tags: vb.net, email, visual-studio-2013, pop3

I'm trying to get a simple email reader working.

I want to give this code a go, as he's had some decent feedback...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18008/Simple-POP-Email-Class

I've downloaded the source, but cant seem to add this into VB in a way that will work.

I keep just seeing 'Type 'SamplePop3Class.POP3' is not defined'.

I hope this isnt too much of a dumb question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by "add this into VB"? the project linked above opens and works fine., no compile errors. the project is named "SamplePop3Class" so if you are trying to use this code in a different project by copying and pasting, you'll have to change the "SamplePop3Class" to the name of your project.

Comment: Thx Rian - its been one hell of a week and my brain is much, I didnt even think to open the project, I was trying to add it as a class *sigh*

Comment: No problem...I added my comment as an answer so it can be accepted. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project linked above opens and works fine, no compile errors. The project is named "SamplePop3Class" so if you are trying to use this code in a different project by copying and pasting, you'll have to change the "SamplePop3Class" to the name of your project.